# AssertionError: HybridBlock requires the first argument to forward be either Symbol or NDArray, but got <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Tags: python, image, numpy, image-processing, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to run a pre-made program on my image, and the image type is a numpy array. When I hit enter, I get this error:

```
AssertionError: HybridBlock requires the first argument to forward be
                either Symbol or NDArray, but got < class 'numpy.ndarray' >
```

Anyone know how to decipher this? When I look online, it says a `NDArray` IS a `numpy.ndarray`, so I'm not sure why it's complaining. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You have to [convert your numpy array to an mxnet NDArray](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/api/python/ndarray/ndarray.html#mxnet.ndarray.array):

```
In [11]: import numpy as np

In [12]: import mxnet as mx

In [13]: a = np.array([1, 2, 3])

In [14]: b = mx.ndarray.array(a)

In [15]: b
Out[15]:

[1. 2. 3.]
<NDArray 3 @cpu(0)>

In [16]: type(b)
Out[16]: mxnet.ndarray.ndarray.NDArray
```

Comment: I tried that and it segued that error into another: raise MXNetError(py_str(_LIB.MXGetLastError()))
mxnet.base.MXNetError: [17:40:02] src/operator/nn/convolution.cc:152: Check failed: dshp.ndim() == 4U (3 vs. 4) : Input data should be 4D in batch-num_filter-y-x ....Any thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: @cbnnbc Same as this issue? https://github.com/Microsoft/MMdnn/issues/311